# Passport user handlebars template

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, passport.js

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
  
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

Here above is the code i used to set my user value in the res.locals.user field.

The console gives me:
{
_id: 5fc3e49c0bfce754c8f923c9,
email: 'myemailadres@hotmail.com',
name: 'Jarne',
password: 'passwordhash......',
__v: 0
}

In my handle bars i'm now trying to use this user variable.

```
{{#if login}}
           welkom 
           {{user.name}}
         
            TESTER
           
{{tester}}
```

This doesn't work. This stays empty..
I can use {{user}} but this give me back the Json format.
How can i access the fields like name, email,... saw some examples in EJS with user.name, user._id but this doesn't seem to work in my handlebars.

Also tried to do this via the router. but same result with tester (tester.name doesn't show anything).

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  res.render('index', {
    title: '---- Dashboard---- HOME',
    tester: req.user
  });

});
```

I also tried to set a res.locals.username = req.user.name
But this resulted in an error.

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution:

```
{{#each user}}
 {{name}}
 {{_id}}
 {{email}}
{{/each}}
```

Looks like i needed to loop through the user object.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I printed out `{{user}}` in `navigation.hbs` it showed the JSON string instead of object
This happened because I used a mongo version that requires `lean()` function after searching the user

add `.lean` function

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user); 
  }).lean()
})
```

hope it helps!